# Smallest multiplier that reveals a factor of a semiprime

Tags: code-golf, primes, binary

Given a [semiprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprime) **N**, find the smallest positive integer **m** such that the binary representation of one of the two factors of **N** can be found in the binary representation of **N * m**.

#### Example

Let's consider the semiprime **N** = **9799**.

We try different values of **m**, starting at 1:

```
 m |  N * m |   N * m in binary
---+--------+------------------
 1 |   9799 |    10011001000111
 2 |  19598 |   100110010001110
 3 |  29397 |   111001011010101
 4 |  39196 |  1001100100011100
 5 |  48995 |  1011111101100011
 6 |  58794 |  1110010110101010
 7 |  68593 | 10000101111110001
 8 |  78392 | 10011001000111000
 9 |  88191 | 10101100001111111
10 |  97990 | 10111111011000110
11 | 107789 | 11010010100001101
```

We stop here because the binary representation of the last product contains `101001` which is the binary representation of **41**, one of the two factors of **9799** (the other one being **239**).

[image: example]

So the answer would be **11**.

#### Rules and notes

- Trying even values of **m** is pointless. They were shown in the above example for the sake of completeness.
- Your program must support any **N** for which **N * m** is within the computing capabilities of your language.
- You are allowed to factorize **N** beforehand rather than trying each possible substring of the binary representation of **N * m** to see if it turns out to be a factor of **N**.
- As [proven by MitchellSpector](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110856/58563), **m** always exists.
- This is code-golf, so the shortest answer in bytes wins. Standard loopholes are forbidden.

#### Test cases

The first column is the input. The second column is the expected output.

```
         N |    m |         N * m |                              N * m in binary | Factor
-----------+------+---------------+----------------------------------------------+-------
         9 |    3 |            27 |                                      [11]011 |      3
        15 |    1 |            15 |                                       [11]11 |      3
        49 |    5 |           245 |                                   [111]10101 |      7
        91 |    1 |            91 |                                    10[1101]1 |     13
       961 |   17 |         16337 |                             [11111]111010001 |     31
      1829 |    5 |          9145 |                             1000[111011]1001 |     59
      9799 |   11 |        107789 |                          1[101001]0100001101 |     41
     19951 |   41 |        817991 |                       1[1000111]101101000111 |     71
    120797 |   27 |       3261519 |                     11000[1110001]0001001111 |    113
   1720861 |  121 |     208224181 |               11000110100[100111111101]10101 |   2557
 444309323 |  743 |  330121826989 |    100110011011100110010[1101010010101011]01 |  54443
 840000701 | 4515 | 3792603165015 | 11011100110000[1000110000111011]000101010111 |  35899
1468255967 |   55 |   80754078185 |      1001011001101010100010[1110001111]01001 |    911
```

Comment: Hmm, I smell an algorithm similar to the ones we used on your Blackjack sequence challenge...

Comment: @ETHproductions Hmm, really? They're honestly supposed to be completely unrelated.

Comment: Well, they're mainly similar in that you need to check every contiguous substring for a specific property. Other than that they really are pretty unrelated.

Comment: "and probably encouraged" - I'm sorry. We don't care about the speed of our code.

Comment: @JanDvorak Fair enough. Removed.

Comment: Perhaps it would be _faster_ to divide N by every substring of N*m, even, and not attempt factorization?

Comment: Don't worry. You can still encourage us, even if it doesn't affect our code.

Comment: In JavaScript particularly, must we support all inputs for which `N*m` is under 2^53, or can we stop at 2^31?

Comment: @ETHproductions Because `2^31` is a limit of the language for certain operations, I'd say that it's OK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Pyth, 13 bytes

```
ff}.BY.B*TQPQ
```

[Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ff%7D.BY.B%2aTQPQ&input=9799&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
ff}.BY.B*TQPQ
f                Find the first integer >= to 1 where the following is true
 f         PQ    Filter the prime factors of the input
        *TQ      Multiply the input by the outer integer
      .B         Convert to a binary string
   .BY           Convert the prime factor to a binary string
  }              Check whether the factor string is in the multiple string.
```

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>18</s> <s>16</s> 15 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to Riley!*

*-1 byte thanks to Emigna!*

```
[N¹*b¹Ñ¦¨båOiNq
```

Explanation:

```
[                   # Infinite loop start
 N                  # Push the amount of times we have iterated
  ¹*               # Multiplied by input
    b              # Convert to binary
     ¹Ñ¦¨b         # Calculate the proper divisors of the input in binary excluding one
          åO       # Check if a substring of N * m in binary is in the divisors
            iNq    # If so, print how many times we have iterated and terminate the program
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#ASUA2v//W07CuSpiwrnDkcKmwqhiw6VPaU5x//85Nzk59W5vLWNhY2hl)

Comment: `¹Ñ¦¨båO` should work instead of checking each substring.

Comment: @Riley thanks for spotting that!

Comment: You can save another byte replacing `¼` and `¾` with `N`.

Comment: @Emigna I didn't know about that trick, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>96</s> <s>95</s> 80 bytes

```
n=>F=m=>(k=p=>p&&(q=1,g=x=>1<x&&x<n&n%x<1|g(x>>1,q*=2))(p)|k(p-q))(n*m)?m:F(-~m)
```

A function which returns a recursive function which uses a recursive function which uses a recursive function. I'm really starting to wonder if the `.toString(2)` route would be shorter...

Assign to a variable e.g. `f=n=>...` and call with an extra pair of parens, `f(9)()`. If that's not allowed (the [meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11317/42545) is at +6/-2), you can use this 83-byte version with standard invocation:

```
f=(n,m)=>(k=p=>p&&(q=1,g=x=>1<x&&x<n&n%x<1|g(x>>1,q*=2))(p)|k(p-q))(n*m)?m:f(n,-~m)
```

Both versions work for all but the last three test cases. You can try these test cases as well by changing `x>>1` to `(x-x%2)/2`.

Comment: Not sure if there's really a consensus about it (we are at [+6/-2](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11317/58563) at the time of posting), but as far as I'm concerned, the first input format is fine.

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Unix utilities, <s>85</s> 84 bytes

```bash
for((;;m++)){ dc -e2o$[$1*m]n|egrep -q $(dc "-e2o`factor $1`nBEPn")&&break;}
echo $m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#S61ITVYwslPQT0kt088rzcn5n5ZfpKFhbZ2rra2pWa2Qkqygm2qUrxKtYqiVG5tXk5pelFqgoFuooKIBlFICySWkJSaX5BcpqBgm5Dm5BuQpaaqpJRWlJmZb13KlJmfkK6jk/v//38LEAAjMDQwB)

---

I'll point out also that m always exists for any semiprime n.  Here's why:

Write n=pq, where p and q are prime and p <= q.

Let b the number of digits in the binary representation of n-1.  Then, for any k between 0 and n-1 inclusive, p*(2^b)+k in binary consists of the binary representation of p followed by b additional bits representing k.

So the numbers p*(2^b)+k for 0 <= k <= n-1, when written in binary, all start with the binary representation of p.  But these are n consecutive numbers, so one of them must be a multiple of n.

It follows that we have a multiple mn of n whose binary representation starts with the binary representation of p.

Based on this, one can come up with an upper bound for m of 2 sqrt(n).  (One can probably get a much tighter upper bound than this.)

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 161 bytes

```
import Data.List
(!)=mod
a#b|a!b==0=b|0<1=a#(b+1)
g 0=[]
g n=g(n`div`2)++show(n!2)
(a%b)c|g b`isInfixOf`g(a*c)=c|0<1=a%b$c+1
f n=min(n%(n#2)$1)$n%(n`div`(n#2))$1
```

Straightforward check. Factor first, then search linearly starting at 1 and take the minimum of the value for both factors.

Takes a few seconds for the last testcase (`1468255967`), `ghci` reports `(15.34 secs, 18,610,214,160 bytes)` on my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, 83 bytes

```
1//.x_/;FreeQ[Fold[#+##&]/@Subsequences@IntegerDigits[x#,2],d_/;1<d<#&&d∣#]:>x+1&
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) (2), 14 bytes

```
ḋḃᵐD∧?:.×ḃs∈D∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@/9wR/fDHc0Pt05wedSx3N5K7/B0ILf4UUcHiP//v6W5peX/KAA)

There's more than one way to write this in 14 bytes in Brachylog, so I went for the most efficient. As is common for Brachylog submissions, this is a function submission; its input is the semiprime, its output is the multiplier.

### Explanation

```
ḋḃᵐD∧?:.×ḃs∈D∧
ḋ               Prime decomposition (finds the two prime factors)
 ḃᵐ             Convert each factor to binary
   D            Name this value as D
    ∧?          Restart with the user input
      :.×       The output is something that can be multiplied by it
         ḃ      to produce a number which, when expressed in binary
          s     has a substring
           ∈D   that is an element of D
             ∧  (suppress an implicit constraint that D is the output; it isn't)
```

Prolog's and Brachylog's evaluation order is set by the first constraint that can't immediately be deduced from the input. In this program, that's a constraint on the result of a multiplication, so the interpreter will aim to keep the operands of the multiplication as close to 0 as possible. We know one of the operands, and the other is the output, so we find the smallest output we can, which is exactly what we want.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 136 bytes

```powershell
param($n)$a=2..($n-1)|?{!($n%$_)}|%{[convert]::ToString($_,2)};for(){$b=[convert]::toString(++$m*$n,2);if($a|?{$b-like"*$_*"}){$m;exit}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@1@QWJSYq6GSp6mSaGukpwdk6Rpq1thXKwJZqirxmrU1qtXRyfl5ZalFJbFWViH5wSVFmXnpGirxOkaatdZp@UUamtUqSbZIakpgarS1VXK1VPKACq0z0zRUEoHGqiTp5mRmpyppqcRrKdUCdeZap1ZkltTW/v//39DIwNzSHAA)

Very lengthy due to how conversion-to-binary works in PowerShell. :-/

Takes input `$n`, loops through `2` to `$n-1` and pulls out the factors `!($n%$_)`. Sends those into a loop `|%{...}` and `convert`s each of them to a binary (base `2`) string. Stores those binary strings into `$a`.

Then we enter an infinite `for(){...}` loop. Each iteration, we increment `++$m`, multiply that by `$n`, and `convert` that to a binary string, stored into `$b`. Then, `if` that string is regex `-like` any strings in `$a`, we output `$m` and `exit`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 66 bytes

```perl6
->\n{first {(n*$_).base(2)~~/@(grep(n%%*,2..^n)».base(2))/},^∞}
```

Regex-based.

Super slow, because it brute-forces the factors of *n* all over again at every regex match position of every number that is tried.

Calculating the factors only once, improves performance but makes it 72 bytes:

```perl6
->\n{my @f=grep(n%%*,2..^n)».base(2);first {(n*$_).base(2)~~/@f/},^∞}
```